# Best way to bulk load data from Azure Synapse Serverless SQL pools into Azure storage or Databricks Spark

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to bulk load data from Azure Synapse serverless SQL pools into Azure Storage or directly into Databricks Spark (using JDBC driver). What is the best way to do this bulk loading assuming we only know the external table name and don't know the location of the file underneath?
Is there any metadata query to know the location of the file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are already in Azure storage since Synapse Serverless SQL has no “in-database” storage.

Assuming it’s an external table (not a view with OPENROWSET) then [sys.external_tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-external-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) has a location column with the path to the file or folder.

If you don’t already know which storage account and container it’s in, you may need to join to [sys.external_data_sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-external-data-sources-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) for that information.